# Does the wall of flesh act like an instagib if it catches you?

Tags: terraria

Simple question: does the wall of flesh kill you instantly if it overtakes you or you touch the wall? What happens if it catches you, apart from taking increased damage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [Terraria wiki states](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall_of_Flesh), the Wall of Flesh does 50 melee damage on contact. You will be dragged toward it if you manage to get behind it and will be killed if you manage to escape.

Comment: If you wind up behind the Wall of Flesh, you will be affected by The Tongue debuff, which pulls you in front of the WoF and does damage to you. If you try to teleport to spawn or outrun the Wall of Flesh by too far, you will die instantly instead.

Comment: Instant death for running too far in front? That's odd- but noted. I am reluctant to accept this as my answer because my question was not actually answered yet. Do you die if the WoF overtakes you. I would infer from what has been said that it simply pushes you along and damages you more. What happens if you get stuck in a wall and the WoF is in your grill then? You can't be dragged through a wall surely? Instant death?

Comment: @defaye "does the wall of flesh kill you instantly if it overtakes you or you touch the wall?" => "You will be dragged toward it if you manage to get behind it". Yes, you will be dragged through walls.

Comment: @defaye - What are you talking about? Running too far in front of the WoF does not mean instant death. He will just pull you toward him and do 50+ melee damage.

Answer (score -1):

If the WoF catches up with you he will do at about 50+ damage. If you manage to behind him you will be affected by the toung debuff which will will drag you right in front of him. Getting too far in front of him will do same exact thing. If you teleport back home you will instantly die,as the message will say (player's name) tried to escape.

Comment: But,why -2? It was kinda hard to come up with something that helped. *sigh*